# Java data structure that signals that a queue has ended/finished?

Tags: java

I am in search for a Java 7 data structure that behaves like a `java.util.Queue` and that additionally has the concept of "final item has been removed".

For example, a concept such as the following one shall be expressible:

```
while(!endingQueue.isFinished()) {
    Element e = endingQueue.remove()
    doSomethingWith(e);
}
```

Comment: Would you not just put a thing in the queue which signals "Final item?".

Comment: @MTilsted I thought about this too... my opinion here currently is that this solution may be problematic: the queue's consumers and the queue's producers would have to agree on what constitutes as the final item... also client code would have to include if-then-else constructs to differentiate the character of an element.

Comment: Is NULL an allowable element in your data? If not, then I would go with  @gilbert-le-blanc 's answer.

Comment: @dtyler Hm, I have the feeling that `null` as a sentinel value can cause problems. But as long as I haven't found a proven robust implementation, I will stick with this "detect `null` item" solution.

Comment: It would be a simple thing just to extend java.util.Queue and then implement 2 extra methods to get/set finalItemState. Should not take more then 7 lines of code in total :}

Answer (score 2):

Using the interface [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), how about

```
while(queue.peek() != null) {
    Element e = queue.remove();
    doSomethingWith(e);
}
```

Edited to answer Abdull's comments:

> By contract, a null item may be a valid entry for a java.util.Queue

You're going to have to point out the specific sentence in the javadoc that says this, because I don't see it.

What I do see is the description of the peek method.

**Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.**

Now, an element in the queue can be null.  But it's still an element, and would be returned by the peek and remove methods.

> Also, think about a concurrently accessed Queue. Just checking for null may not be enough to decide whether a producer has or hasn't put an element to the queue.

Queue is an interface.  You would have to test this with a concrete implementation, like [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).  If none of the concrete implementations do what you want, you're free to implement Queue yourself.

The Queue interface provides a method to see if there's an element in the queue.

The ConcurentLinkedQueue class provides an additional method to see if there's an element in the queue, isEmpty.

Test and see if you encounter actual performance problems, rather than worrying about possible performance problems that may or may not happen.

Comment: [By contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), a `null` item may be a valid entry for a `java.util.Queue`. Also, think about a concurrently accessed `Queue`. Just checking for `null` may not be enough to decide whether a producer has or hasn't put an element to the queue.

Comment: Thank you for updating. According to Java 7 Javadoc, *Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements.*....  So my interpretation here is, that most generally with the `java.util.Queue` interface, it is unspecified what happens when a `null` item is added to a `java.util.Queue`.

Comment: Queue inherits from Collection, so if you're truly concerned use Collection.isEmpty() instead.

Comment: @Abdull: My interpretation of that sentence is "Don't add a null to a queue".  Problem solved.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I couldn't find some method `isFinished` in class `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Comment: @Abdull: Sorry, the method is isEmpty.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you for updating again! ... to clarify my ambiguous requirements: in the `Queue` I am looking for, `isEmpty()` and `isFinished()` are two independent concepts. For example, temporarily, the queue may be *empty*, but it may be still a long time until it is *finished*: a producer may still add more elements to the queue.

Comment: @Abdull: That's a different question. :-)  You're going to have to put your code in a timer loop, so that you check the queue every so often.  You have to determine how often.  Your code goes to sleep when the queue is empty, and wakes up after a period of time to check the queue again.